# Perdition vs Hell

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the religious connotations of *Perdition* and *Hell*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Perdition* is the name, in Christian theology, of the state of eternal punishment. *Hell* is the name given in many religions to a place where evil resides, and where people may be confined to after death, as a punishment for their behaviour during their life.

So: *hell* is a place, and it is a concept shared between many religions; *perdition* is a state, and it is a specifically Christian concept.

---

Definitions are those of the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> **perdition**: (in Christian theology) a state of eternal punishment and damnation into which a sinful and unpenitent person passes after death.
>
> **hell**: a place regarded in various religions as a spiritual realm of evil and suffering, often traditionally depicted as a place of perpetual fire beneath the earth where the wicked are punished after death.

Comment: I'm not very sure about the distinctions between state and place, let me have a  look at other answers

Comment: @F'x: It'd be great if you could expand your answer a bit and add a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @n0nChun: just say what you don't understand, or what point you want details on, I'll try to help some more

Comment: No man, it's just that the answer needs something more. I hope you understand, or you could cite your references for that matter.

Comment: Added references. Otherwise, if you need “something more” but cannot say what, I'm afraid I cannot help :)

Comment: _Perdition_ is to _Hell_ as _Eternal Life_ is to _Heaven_. Perdition is somewhat equivalent to "damned" but after damnation occurs. Hell is where that damnation happens. (Note: I am completely skipping over the theological implications here. I am guessing that those are not within the scope of this site.)

Answer (score 3):

Both, Perdition and Hell are the same, but Hell seems to be a more universal place. As F'x has said its concept and name are shared between several religions, for example there is Helheim in Scandinavian mythology where a goddess (well, not actually a goddess, but to keep it simple...) named Hel lives and rules. Perdition is more specific, I think, and also it means destruction, death and downfall that is why Judas is called Son of Perdition.